# Toggle Display on/off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM and I have a situation where I have HTML generated dynamically. It's possible, even probable that the same HTML will be used in more that one place on the page. I have a div with data in it that I only want to be displayed when the user clicks the header div. IE:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="$(this).children('div:first').toggle();">This is Div 1</div>        
<div style="display:none">
<p>I'm hidden</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do is when the user clicks on the Click Me link the child  toggles its display on and off. Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished without some convoluted ID scheme? (I've thought of at least two).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you posted, the div containing "I'm hidden" is not a child of the first div.

You can use $.eq() to select a specific children index: https://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
<div onclick="$(this).children('div').eq(0).toggle();">
    This is Div 1
    <div style="display:none">
        <p>I'm hidden</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4zLb106/) (with "hidden div" child of Div1)

If you need to toggle visibility of a sibling, you can use $.siblings() https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ or $.next() https://api.jquery.com/next/

```
<div onclick="$(this).next().toggle();">
    This is Div 1
</div>
<div style="display:none">
    <p>I'm hidden and I'm a sibling</p>
</div>
```

See [JSFiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/5ex68art/) (hidden div sibling of Div1)

Comment: Nice. Thanks , it works. The first line shouldn't have ended with </div>.

Answer (score 0):

you can tie an event to the Click Me and in javascript/jquery, find the first child div after "this" (the div that was clicked).  Something like this:

```
$(this).children("div:first");
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried both :first and div:first. It stays hidden. I also looked at $(this).find